# Give axes and tick markers priority over plotted line

Tags: matlab, plot

The default plot behaviour in Matlab is to overwrite axes and tick marks with the line to be plotted. For instance in the figure below near the origin the x-axis is overwritten and the tick-marker for 0.004 is also overwritten.

Is there a way to have the axes and tick marks have priority over the plotted line?

[image]

Comment: You can set axes and ticks to whatever values you want using `set(gca,'xtick',...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the axes `Layer` property to `'top'`.

```
set(gca,'Layer','top');
```