# Give axes priority over plotted line without giving grid priority

Tags: matlab, plot

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556804/give-axes-and-and-tick-markers-priority-over-plotted-line) I asked how to give axes and tick marks priority over the plotted line. The correct solution was:

```
set(gca,'Layer','top');
```

However in the case that I also want to plot a grid on the figure this gives the grid priority over the plotted lines as shown in the attached figure when exported as an `.eps` file. This is undesirable and leads to a dashed appearance to the blue line.

[image]

How can I give priority to axes and tick marks but not give priority to the grid?

Comment: I don't see this behaviour in MATLAB 2016a? What version are you using? Would be useful to post a plot command that reproduces the problem...

Comment: @Justin I forgot to mention that this is when saved as an `.eps` file and opened as a `.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`'Layer'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-Layer) of an axes object controls the layering of the axes, tick marks, and grid lines, so they can't be layered separately. Your options are:

- Stack a couple of axes on top of each other with the same limits, with the bottom axes having grid lines and no data plotted and the top axes having your data and axes ticks that are layered on top.
- Plot your grid lines yourself first, then plot your data on top of them, For example:

  ```
  [xGridv, yGridv] = meshgrid([0.1 0.2 0.3], [0 1.7]);  % Vertical grid lines
  [yGridh, xGridh] = meshgrid([0.5 1 1.5], [0 0.32]);   % Horizontal grid lines
  hold on;
  plot(xGridv, yGridv, 'k:');
  plot(xGridh, yGridh, 'k:');
  % Plot your data
  ```